# Error when get ID in jquery

Tags: php, jquery

I have a code php:

```
<?php
for ($i=0, $n=count( $this->item ); $i < $n; $i++) {
$row = &$this->item[$i];
?>
<tr id="<?php echo $row->id; ?>" class="row">
<span id="name_<?php echo $row->id; ?>" class="text">&nbsp;<?php echo $row->name; ?></span>
<input type="text" value="<?php echo $row->name; ?>" class="editbox" id="name_input_<?php echo $row->id; ?>" />
</tr>
<?php
$i++;
}
?>
```

and Jquery get id from this script php

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.row').click(function(){
       var ID = $(this).attr('id');
       $('#name_'+ID).hide(); 
       $('#name_input_'+ID).show();
       alert(ID); 
    });
});
</script>
```

Error when i output alert(ID) result is NULL, How to get ID ?

Comment: in your php echo the value of $row->id and check whether it is assigned a vale or not

Comment: Show us the output HTML from that PHP code. Also in your Javascript just use `this.id` instead of `$(this).attr('id')` since it's a lot faster.

Comment: $i++ again at end of loop...!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this....

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
$('.row').click(function(){
   var ID = $(this).closest('tr').attr('id');
   $('#name_'+ID).hide(); 
   $('#name_input_'+ID).show();
   alert(ID); 
  });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

i think the problem in your html code table must look like this :

```
<table>
  <tr> 
   <td></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

change to :

```
<?php
for ($i=0, $n=count( $this->item ); $i < $n; $i++) {
$row = &$this->item[$i];
?>
<tr id="<?php echo $row->id; ?>" class="row">
<td>
<span id="name_<?php echo $row->id; ?>" class="text">&nbsp;<?php echo $row->name; ?></span>
<input type="text" value="<?php echo $row->name; ?>" class="editbox" id="name_input_<?php echo $row->id; ?>" />
</td>
</tr>
<?php
$i++;
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

you may be having issues with the main div ID itself - it should not start with a number http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_standard_id.asp - rather use a name with the ID suffix and then remove the prefix to get the number value.

try this on the tr: `<tr id="rowid_<?php echo $row->id; ?>" class="row">`

and then in your code:

```
    $('.row').click(function(){
           var rowid = $(this).attr('id');
var ID = rowid.replace(/rowid_/,'');
           $('#name_'+ID).hide(); 
           $('#name_input_'+ID).show();
           alert(ID); 
        });
```